# Javascript select option keeps showing a '0' before value

Tags: javascript, parseint

I'm having an issue with getting the value of a select option and calculating it, the issue is that everytime i select an option a random '0' keeps being displayed before it. Any help would be appreciated, here is the relevant code:

```
               <div class="otherCars">  
                    <label for="otherCars">Do you drive any other cars?</label> 
                    <select name="otherCars" class="style1" id="carsSelect"  onchange="getQuote()" onblur="validateSelect('cars')" >
                        <option value="empty">-Please select-</option>
                        <option value="10" id="car1">No access to any other cars </option>
                        <option value="20">Own another car</option>
                        <option value="100">Named driver on another policy</option>
                        <option value="100">Company car (including personal use)</option>
                        <option value="100">Company car (excluding personal use)</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- Closing div tag-->
```

Javascript:

```
function getQuote(){
var disqualifiedDifference = 0;
var genderDifference = 0;
var carDifference = 0;
var menuSelect = document.getElementById("carsSelect");
var carValue = menuSelect.options[menuSelect.selectedIndex].value;

function genderPrice(){
    if (document.getElementById("male").checked){
        genderDifference += 200;
        }
    if (document.getElementById("female").checked){
        genderDifference += 175;
        }
        } 

function disqoPrice(){
    if (document.getElementById("yes").checked){
        disqualifiedDifference += 300;
        }
    if (document.getElementById("no").checked){
        disqualifiedDifference += 0;
        }
        } 

function carPrice(){
    if (document.getElementById("car1").selected){
        carDifference += 200;
        }
    if (document.getElementById("car2").selected){
        carDifference += 20;
        }
        }



genderPrice();
disqoPrice();

    var totalPrice = disqualifiedDifference + genderDifference + carDifference + carValue;
    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = totalPrice;
} //end of CalculateTotal
```

Comment: Try `parseInt` on your car value

Comment: working with unique option values make things easier

Comment: @SterlingArcher irrelevant for the question or in general?

Comment: Kind of both. Select option values don't have to be unique, because in this case, different car options can cost the same. So having a unique option value wont make things easier, it will just make values unique.

Comment: @SterlingArcher in 29 years I'll be retired, at that time, if I used a select this way more than 3 times, I'll comeback to this question and admit that you were 100% right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`menuSelect.options[menuSelect.selectedIndex].value` returns a string, which means that the `+` operator will be performing string concatenation rather than addition. Cast the value to a `Number` before trying to do arithmetic.

```
var carValue = +menuSelect.options[menuSelect.selectedIndex].value;
//             ^ unary + operator casts a string to a number
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of the unary operator like that. I would have suggested using `Number()` but this is pretty cool. I'll have to keep that in mind!

Comment: Unary operators are awesome. Little faster than `Number()` but at the cost of readability

Comment: @SterlingArcher: I'd qualify something that's a little bit faster at the cost of readability as terribly not awesome.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, I don't find the unary `+` operator to be less readable per-se, it's just not a feature that most introductory courses cover. In the same way that I don't consider `foo = bar ? baz : qux;` less readable than `if (bar) { foo = baz; } else { foo = qux; }`. I *do* find unary `+` less readable if it's part of a complex equation, so I generally adhere to a "no more than 2 operations per line" policy. In this example it's assignment and unary `+`.